# Bibliography more authors of the same year a/b/c wrong order

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem in my bibliography, I have several sources of the same author in the same year. They are automatically supplemented in the bibliography with a/b/c and so on. In the PDF output they are displayed in the wrong (at least not the right for me) order.

```
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex8,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  dashed=false,
  hyperref=true,
  maxbibnames=9,
  maxcitenames=3,
  firstinits=true,
  isbn=false,
  url=false
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} % no prefix «S.» before page in citation
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace} % colon instead of dot before title
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}} %et al. instead of u.a.
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
```

These are my entries from the bibliography file:

```
@Misc{2016Kommissiononline2,
  Title                    = {Single European Sky},
  Author                   = {{Europäische Kommission}},
  HowPublished             = {\url{http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/single_european_sky/index_en.htm}. Zugriff am: 15.07.16},
  Year                     = {2016},
  Owner                    = {lebster},
  Timestamp                = {2016.07.12},
  Url                      = {http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/single_european_sky/index_en.htm}
}

@Misc{2016Kommissiononline23,
  Title                    = {Single European Sky 2+},
  Author                   = {{Europäische Kommission}},
  HowPublished             = {\url{http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/single_european_sky/ses2plus_en.htm}. Zugriff am: 27.07.16},
  Year                     = {2016},
  Owner                    = {lebster},
  Timestamp                = {2016.07.15},
  Url                      = {http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/single_european_sky/ses2plus_en.htm}
}
```

This is the respective output:

[image: PDF output]

Has anyone an idea how to get the a/b/c entries in an alphabetical order?

Comment: Interesting problem, I could reproduce the problem with `backend=bibtex8`, with the recommended `backend=biber`, however, everything is fine. You could add a `sortyear` field to the entries to override the incorrect sorting.