# Corporate authors not sorted alphabetically

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style, sorting

I'm using *natbib* with the *apalike-german.bst* and a bibliography in *alphabetical* order. I need to cite some ***corporate authors*** in my thesis. However these are unfortunately not included alphabetically, but added at the end of my bibliography.

I've tried different things, but I just can't seem to solve the problem. I would like to change the sorting function in the bst file, but I'm not that advanced yet. Can anybody help me?

Here is my MWE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{natbib}         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@misc{kredo,
    author = {{Kompetenzzentrum für Rechtsextremismus- und Demokratieforschung}},
    Title  = "\emph{Die Leipziger "`Mitte''-Studien}",
    Note   = "\url{https://www.kredo.uni-leipzig.de/die-leipziger-mitte-studien/}
    [abgerufen am 17.07.2017]",
    year = 2017,
}

@book{salzborn,
    title = {Rechtsextremismus: {Erscheinungsformen} und {Erklärungsansätze}},
    publisher = {Nomos},
    author = {Salzborn, Samuel},
    year = {2015},
    Note   = {2., aktualisierte und erweiterte Auflage.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{salzborn}
\citep{kredo}

\bibliography{MWE}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-german}

\end{document}
```

The "Kompetenzzentrum für Rechtsextremismus- und Demokratieforschung" is sorted after "Salzborn", but should be before. Can anybody help me?

@Johannes_B: Here are the first 5 lines of my log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.5.2)  23 JUL 2017 21:01
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**MWE.tex
```

And everything after File List:

```
*File List*
memoir.cls    2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article 
document cl
ass
ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
mem10.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
ngerman.ldf    2013/12/13 v2.7 German support for babel (new 
orthography)
natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
hyperref.sty    2016/05/05 v6.83n Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset 
hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic 
(HO)
hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error         
messages (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/10 v0.21 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)   
hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
pd1enc.def    2016/05/05 v6.83n Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
memhfixc.sty    2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for             
memoir clas
s
hpdftex.def    2016/05/05 v6.83n Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
 MWE.out
 MWE.out
 MWE.bbl
 ***********

 Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 34.
 Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `MWE.out' has not changed.
 (rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 
 AB240A2148FED1296325C3FC61E2DB9E;56.
 Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 34.
 ) 
 Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8597 strings out of 493014
 120812 string characters out of 6133352
 239818 words of memory out of 5000000
 12103 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5357 words of font info for 20 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 32i,10n,25p,204b,336s stack positions out of 
 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 </usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-
 dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb
 ></usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-
 dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-
 dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></
 usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-
 dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
 Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 54892 bytes).
 PDF statistics:
 44 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 36 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 6 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 9 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

@moewe This is my .blg-file:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: MWE.aux
The style file: apalike-german.bst
"}" is missing in command: macro---line 767 of file apalike-german.bst
 : macro {mar} {"M\"
 :                  {a}rz"}
Database file #1: MWE.bib
You've used 2 entries,
            1931 wiz_defined-function locations,
            483 strings with 4034 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 533 in all, are:
= -- 53
> -- 14
< -- 2
+ -- 4
- -- 4
* -- 32
:= -- 109
add.period$ -- 7
call.type$ -- 2
change.case$ -- 10
chr.to.int$ -- 2
cite$ -- 2
duplicate$ -- 24
empty$ -- 39
format.name$ -- 6
if$ -- 102
int.to.chr$ -- 1
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 2
newline$ -- 14
num.names$ -- 6
pop$ -- 10
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 20
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 24
swap$ -- 1
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 10
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 4
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 28
(There was 1 error message)
```

Comment: Welcome, excellent MWE. Unfortunately, i don't have the bst file. Can you post a link where to get it?

Comment: @Johannes_B https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apalike-german?

Comment: @moewe Still running TL 2015 :-) Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: Ah, I see. I get an error from the `.bst` about `MACRO {mar} {"M\"{a}rz"}`. But the sorting is OK.

Comment: @Johannes_B Interestingly I remember that `biblatex` with BibTeX as backend would have a similar problem. Corporate authors would sort under `{` at the end. See [How to sort corporate authors along personal authors with bibtex sorting=anyt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372093/35864).

Comment: Off-topic: Write `Auf"|lage` rather than `Auflage` if you want to suppress the `fl`-ligature.

Comment: Can you confirm that you get the incorrect sorting in the MWE you posted? Can you check your version of `apalike-german.bst`? (I think there is only one, but better make sure. Mine is 11-sep-2016).

Comment: I get the expected sorting.

Comment: Thank you. @Johannes_b & moewe yes that's the one (11-sep-2016). That's so weird. I constantly get that mistake with all three corporate authors in the file and also if I run the MWE (even after downloading the bst-file again).

Comment: Please add \listfiles at the very top of the MWE and post the end of the log file (where the file list will be) as well as the first five lines to the question.

Comment: Mhhh, my versions of some of the packages are newer than yours, but not by much. And I don't think those that differ should cause problems here. Can you show us the `.blg` file?

Comment: Mhhh, I'm out of my depth here. My `.blg` looks similar, we get the same error. But since BibTeX soldiers on regardless I didn't think that would influence the sorting. egreg and I get the expected sorting from your MWE and you get the incorrect sorting....

Comment: @moewe Did you report the bug to the author?

Comment: @Johannes_B Which one? The BibTeX sorting problem in `biblatex` or the `apalike-german.bst` März?

Comment: @moewe I guess the biblatex bug is fixed by now? I meant März. If you didn' t yet, would you mind reporting?

Comment: @Johannes_B Mhhh, I have not reported the `biblatex` bug, but I probably should. It will probably not be high up on the list of priorities, but maybe Joseph has a look at it and an idea. I can report the März thingy.

Comment: @Johannes_B No problem, both project have GitHub pages, so it went rather quickly. https://github.com/CarlOrff/apalike-german/issues/1 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/601 if you are interested.

Comment: @moewe Just got the mail ping for biblatex :-)